# LINQ CSV Database - Quick way for except

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a pair CSV Files.

CSV1 :
Option Number , Product Number , Product Name

CSV2 :
Product Number , Product Details , Product Details

The number of records is very high , number of files (pairs generated weekly) is also very high.

CSV2 will have some of the Product details , manually the Product Details are entered.

How can I :
1.Re Generate CSV1 to have only those Product Number (and Option and Name) for those Products whose details do not exist in CSV2

Tried LINQ to CSV from code project , able to read / write fine 
but the EXCEPT part takes a lot of time.

```
var query =    
    from c in dc.Customers    
    where !(from o in dc.Orders    
            select o.CustomerID)    
           .Contains(c.CustomerID)    
    select c;
```

This is the equivalent , but still too slow.

How can I trim all the fields retrieved using the query.
If I am to set the type to int - Product Number.
That should help. Please provide your feedback. I can provide the code.
But it is mostly based on LINQTOCSV from codeproject.

Comment: hm, csv1 has product info, csv2 has also product info, why sample query is then about customers and orders?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the product numbers from CSV2 in a [hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) and then your where clause could become:

```
  where !hashSet.Contains(productID)
```

which performance should be better (O(1))

Answer (score 0):

Products from both files select to dictionaries, where key is product number and then compare, it will be faster.